# Having trouble returning the result of a requests call to an api because of headers

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm making an api that calls on another API. Everything works really well until I add the headers to the return int the form of

```
response.headers.items()
```

the return looks like this when it works:

```
res_dict = response.json()
return (jsonify(res_dict), response.status_code)
```

and like this when it doesn't:

```
res_dict = response.json()
return (jsonify(res_dict), response.status_code, response.headers.items())
```

When I print the actual response.headers.items() I get the following

```
ItemsView({
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'x-correlation-id':'cd28f05e-df35-49bd-a17d-868c185fd640',
   'badi':'Routing: us-east-1=>us-east-1; Version: 4001; Host: c6c8;',
   'Cache-Control':'private',
   'Access-Control-Expose-Headers':'X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Reset',
   'x-frame-options':'SAMEORIGIN',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
   'x-content-type-options':'nosniff, nosniff',
   'Content-Encoding':'gzip',
   'X-RateLimit-Limit':'40',
   'X-RateLimit-Remaining':'39',
   'X-RateLimit-Reset':'2',
   'Server':'no-name-at-all',
   'X-XSS-Protection':'1; mode=block',
   'Content-Length':'108',
   'Date':'Tue, 11 Jun 2019 19:03:00 GMT',
   'Connection':'keep-alive',
   'Vary':'Accept-Encoding',
   'Set-Cookie':'pipe-last-active=1560279780260;path=/;domain=.pipedrive.com;expires=0',
   'Server-Timing':'cdn-cache; desc=MISS, edge; dur=97, origin; dur=37',
   'Strict-Transport-Security':'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains'
})
```

And when I try get the url in firefox them to the client it returns an error like this:

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Any help fixing this problem is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm the `res_dict` data is actually JSON? The `Content-Encoding` header is specifying gzip, so could be what's causing an issue - both when you read and return the data

Comment: Changed the encoding of the response to gzip and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  dylanj.nz I was finally able to resolve this problem and it was very simple. The `Content-Encoding` header was set to `gzip` so I had to change the encoding of the response. by the end the response return code look like this.

```
res_gzip = gzip.compress(response.content)
return (res_gzip, response.status_code, response.headers.items())
```

of course using the gzip library in python which is included with the interpreter it seems.

Anyway, thank you very much it was great help